# Errors compiling ArangoDB on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, arangodb

I'm compiling ArangoDB 3.2.3 from source on my RaspberryPi 3 Model B. I'm adapting the build process from here: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/operations/installation/compiling/compile-on-debian/

`cmake` runs fine, but `make` gives the following errors:

```
[  1%] Performing build step for 'v8_build'
  CXX(target) /home/pi/arango-src/ArangoDB-3.2.3/build/3rdParty/V8/v5.7.0.0/ia32.release/obj.target/icui18n/third_party/icu/source/i18n/affixpatternparser.o
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse2’
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mfpmath=sse’
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mmmx’
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, and we also don't answer homework questions. Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. For further information, please see how to ask good questions, and take the tour of the site =]

Answer (score 3):

OK, I got some feedback on ArangoDB's slack channel. Apparently the DBMS requires an ARM7 CPU, so it's not possible to compile it for the RaspberryPi.

Comment: Official ARM builds are meanwhile available for Linux and macOS. On Linux, at least a 64-bit ARMv8 with NEON SIMD extension is required.